# Highcharts html legend, what column was clicked

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I create a legend that is html I would like to know the element that was clicked. Hichgharts does not seem to have that tucked in there anywhere.

Here is some sample code:

```
          point:{
            events:{
                legendItemClick:function(event){
                   //how to get the element clicked here?
                   //want something to happen if it has a class of pieLegendNumber
```

And the code creating the legend:

```
   legend : {
    enabled: true,
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    useHTML: true,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
     labelFormatter: function() {
        return '<div style="width:150px;"><span style="float:left;width: 230px;min-width: 230px;">' 
            + this.name
            + '<span style="float:right;color:red" class="pieLegendNumber">' 
            + this.y
            + '</span></div>';
     }
   },
   title:{
     text:"legend"
   },
```

The whole code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgxa62z1/1/).

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `index` property of data point to get legend element which has been clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/bgxa62z1/4/

Hope this helps

**[Update]**

You can use `event.browserEvent.target` or sometimes if you add the handler to the series.event.click you can use `event.originalEvent.target` to get the element that has been clicked.

Solution http://jsfiddle.net/bgxa62z1/7/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to know what column is clicked. So do something when the browser name is clicked but do something else when number is clicked.

Comment: Yes, as I suggested in a comment to Emre I will look into such a solution. Problems with this are: 1. When drilling down the handlers no longer work. you could solve this by doing `$('#container').click(".pieLegendNumber",function(event) {` (as in the comment to Emre) but that would still drill down when clicking on a number. See modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgxa62z1/6/

Answer (score 0):

As mantioned in the [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.events.legendItemClick), `legendItemClick` is *not* applicable to pie charts.

So, I made same small changes on your jsFiddle demo and it is now working.

Here is the solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgxa62z1/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what exactly does it have to do with the question? When I click on an item in the legend I need to know the column that was clicked. Passed event and invoking object (this) do not seem to hold any information as to what element was clicked. The fiddle shows a working example for `plotoptions.point.events.click`. Maybe I will just use `$(hichartContainer).click(".pieLegendNumber",function...`

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. Yes, object has no information about clicked element.